# Android Studio connection to a physical device

Tags: android, flutter, android-studio, connection, usb-debugging

I connect my phone Realme 6s (RMX2002) to my device and the USB debugging is enabled.
Android Studio recognized & connected but doesn't show the app project in flutter [like in the photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YDIPJ.jpg)
So, any suggestions to figure this out?

Answer (score 1):

You need to check your USB cable. They are in two types, one of which only supports phone charging.

Answer (score 0):

I can't quite understand what you're asking here, but according to your photo, no device is selected to debug on.

My advice is to (save) =) and restart Android Studio. Make sure that the RSA fingerprint for your computer is accepted on the phone. Try restarting your phone and reconnecting. Double check that USB debugging is enabled.

I cannot tell what is really going on, it may be an issue with the ADB. Check your Event Log to make sure the ADB debug bridge started successfully.
If you simply try to run your app on an emulator, issues of this kind will be promptly visible.

If you can ascertain that it is not an issue with ADB, Android Studio, or your phone, it is probably a driver issue with your computer, if you are on Windows.
Try this link: https://www.thecustomdroid.com/oppo-realme-usb-drivers/ to install the USB drivers for your computer.

Cheers!

Comment: Thanks for reply ! As what you said, YES there is no device or emulator selected to debug on. I tried everything you said previosly. Thanks any way

Comment: Sometimes there will just be devices out there that won't agree with Android Studio no matter what you try. I recommend trying a different device if possible, like a Samsung or Galaxy, if you have one on hand. Good luck!

Comment: It isn't an issue with your cable as @Evgen said. It wouldn't have connected to Android Studio if it wasn't a data transferring cable.

Answer (score 0):

I a had also problem with USB debugging and it was the cable's fault.
An alternative option is to use wireless debugging. A step-by-step guide for Android studio can be found here:  https://link.medium.com/UQJWZrfFqob